# Export PHPExcel write long number cell - code igniter

Tags: excel, codeigniter, phpexcel, export-to-excel

While writing the excel file is fine I see that really long numbers are formulas in excel

Example: 3.21E+15

instead of: 3210142008810000

How can I change the format during the PHP Excel Creation?

My code

```
$object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0, $excel_row, $row->member);
```

and i try code

```
$object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit(0, $excel_row, $row->member, PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
```

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: PHPExcel_Exception

Message: Invalid cell coordinate 0

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP Excel's `setCellValueExplicit` requires an alphanumeric coordinate: `A1`, `C27`, etc. Basically, you need to give the cell coordinates in one value.

Since you apparently write on the first column only, try this:

```
$coordinate = 'A' . $excel_row;

$object->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit(
    $coordinate, 
    $row->member,
    PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING
);
```

---

**Note**:
PHP Excel is deprecated, you should try [PHP Spreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet). It's developed by the same vendor and it has a similar API.

Comment: its works, thanks @silviu-g solution for my problem will be very helpful.

Comment: Glad to be of service. Please don't forget mark the answer as accepted if helped you (click on the gray checkmark beside my answer - it will turn green to indicate you accepted the answer)